# Tkinter having issues opening new frames

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frames

I've linked my button to open ProjecMain.py on clicking and am recieving errors with this but i dont quite understand them and why they are occurring i will copy both pages into here.

TkintGUI.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tm
import ProjecMain

from pip._vendor.cachecontrol import controller



class LoginFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):


        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (LoginScreen,ProjecMain):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            self.show_frame(LoginScreen)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class LoginScreen(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.label_1 = tk.Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_2 = tk.Label(self, text="Password")

        self.entry_1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_2 = tk.Entry(self, show="*")


        self.label_1.grid(row=0)
        self.entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.label_2.grid(row=1)
        self.entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Keep me logged in")
        self.checkbox.grid(columnspan=2)

        self.logbtn = tk.Button(self, text="Login", command=self.login_btn)
        self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)

        self.pack()


def login_btn(self):
        #print("On click action/event")
        Username = self.entry_1.get()
        Password = self.entry_2.get()

        if Username == "Lewis" and Password == "starwars10":
            lambda:controller.show_frame(ProjecMain)
        else:
            tm.showerror("Login error", "Incorrect Login details")


app = LoginFrame()
app.mainloop()
```

ProjecMain.py

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tm

import TkintGUI



class ProjecMain(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.Random_label = tk.Label(self, text="Random Label")



app = ProjecMain()
app.mainloop()
```

And these are the errors i'm receiving

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lewis Collins\Python Project\GUI\TkintGUI.py", line 6, in <module>
    from GUI import ProjecMain
  File "C:\Users\Lewis Collins\Python Project\GUI\ProjecMain.py", line 12, in <module>
    app = ProjecMain()
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'parent' and 'controller'
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: in class `ProjectMain` you have `__init__(self, parent, controller)` so you need to run `ProjectMain(some_parent, some_controller)`. But you don't have to use `app = ProjectMain(...)` and you shouldn't run second `mainloop`

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you exactly what is wrong:

> TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'parent' and 'controller'

That means that `ProjectMain` requires 2 positional arguments, one named `parent` and one named `controller`. You are creating the class without those parameters in this line of code at the bottom of ProjectMain.py:

```
app = ProjectMain()
```

If your intention is to use `ProjectMain` from within TkintGUI.py, you must remove that line, and the call to `mainloop()` in ProjectMain.py. Your main application is responsible for creating an instance of this class.